# pod repo push keeps using an old commit

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, git, cocoapods

For example, I create a tag and run:

```
pod repo push --allow-warnings myPodspecsRepo ../MyPod.podspec
```

Then, if for example a unit test is failing, I get a warning. After that I fix, commit & push it. I move the tag by deleting it locally & remotely, and then creating it anew.

If I then execute the `repo push` command again, I still get the old error, since it keeps using the first position of the tag, which forces me to create a new version.

Is there a way to make the command use the new commit for the tag?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. `pod cache clean myPod`
2. `pod repo push --allow-warnings myPodspecsRepo ../MyPod.podspec`
3. `pod repo update`

CocoaPods assumes that a versions are immutable and caches accordingly. To change what a version means, the local cache needs to be cleared.

Answer (score 0):

1. open Finder and go to `~/.cocoapods/repos`
2. delete the **REPO_NAME** folder
3. then open the terminal again and run `pod repo add [REPO_NAME] [SOURCE_URL]`
4. then again run `pod repo push [REPO_NAME] [POD_NAME].podspec`